# AutoMapper dictionary to class - how to ignore unsupported property mapping?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to convert dynamic objects of type Dictionary<string, object> to typed classes. Automapper allows that by default without need to create explicit map:

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Automapper goes through keys in dictionary and when there is match with property name in destination class it tries to set the property. However it throws exception when conversion fails.

Is there a way to setup the mapper to map only those items from source dictionary that are convertible and ignore items that could not be converted? In the example bellow instance result of type Sample1 is populated correctly.

```
public class Sample1
{
    public string str_number { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_from { get; set; }
}

var dynamicItems = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    ["str_number"] = 123456,
    ["description"] = "lorem ipsum",
    ["date_from"] = "2023-11-27"
};

var mapperConf = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {});
var mapper = new Mapper(mapperConf);
var result = mapper.Map<Sample1>(dynamicItems);
```

But if I change e.g. ["date_from"] to value "2023-11-27xxx" in dictionary then Automapper throws exception. I'd like to get result with property date_from unset (default value).

Edit:

I found a solution by using JSON serialization with NewtonSoft package. Error handler in JsonSerializerSettings does the trick that only convertible properties are set a the other remain with default values.

```
private static T Convert<T>(IDictionary<string, object> cmProperties) where T : class, new()
{
    // ignore properties that could not be converted to destination type
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = (_, eventArgs) =>
        {
            eventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    };

    // serialize dictionary to JSON
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cmProperties);

    // deserialize JSON to typed class or return new empty instance
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings) ?? new T();
}
```

Comment: You can create a map from string to date that does what you need.

Comment: I wanted something more flexible. The destination type should be number etc. I'd have to write map for each destination type to ignore exceptions.

Comment: Then you can write your own version of the ConvertMapper. I think that's the one that handles from string conversions. But you'd need to get familiar with the AM code base :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I updated the question with solution using serialization and deserialization.  I was looking for some switch in AutoMapper similar to error handler in NewtonSoft Json serializer settings. :-)

Comment: Hopefully performance is not a concern. Because that seems expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If your date time string can be clumsy and must be cleaned, you have to define a specific converter from *string* to *DateTime*. This can be done via a Profile and the most easiest (and currently failing) approach would be:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<string, DateTime>()
            .ConvertUsing(source => DateTime.Parse(source));
    }
}
```

This has to be added to your configuration:

```
var mapperConf = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>(); });
var mapper = new Mapper(mapperConf);
var result = mapper.Map<Sample1>(dynamicItems);
```

While this still fails as in your original code, you now have an entry point where you can do something. To avoid your given example wit some invalid suffix, you could shorten the string before parsing:

```
CreateMap<string, DateTime>()
    .ConvertUsing(source => DateTime.Parse(source.Substring(0, 10)));
```

If your logic to extract the desired date time information from the given string is more complex and doesn't fit into a simple lambda, you could provide a corresponding converter and do whatever is needed to turn the given string into a meaningful date time object:

```
public class StringDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(string source, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return DateTime.TryParse(source[..10], out DateTime result)
            ? result
            : DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<string, DateTime>()
            .ConvertUsing<StringDateTimeConverter>();
    }
}
```

If your mapping should fail or if you return a placeholder folder or an approximate value is up to you. Just implement your expectation into the *Convert()* method of the converter and it does what you want.